# R with xts subsetting: start date plus setting range

Tags: r, xts

While subsetting with xts you usually set the range between two dates/times e.g.

```
df["T08:00/T16:59"]
```

or

```
df["2012-12-12/2012-12-12"]
```

I wanna set the start date and get a special period: e.g 14 days. How would you solve that problem, calculating a 2nd external variable. Or is it also possible to set the range of the subset?

Example: `df["2012-12-12/14days.."]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
first(df["2012-12-12/"], "14 days")
```

Comment: Perfect - I am a beginner in R and wondering sometimes how easy it is to combine functions an packages. How did you learn this?

Comment: @HerrStudent, I learned it from [the quantmod website](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/data/#subset).  Also, `help(package="xts", help_type="html")` and `vignette(package="xts")` are very useful.